# Finding the direction using vectors

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I have this question that I have no idea were to start and I would like a push in the right direction.

A boat has a sail surface of 10m^2 and traveling N40°E. And wind is 6m/s from N30°W. What is the best angle to sail at. 
We are assuming the keel of the boat is N40°E, the sail is flat and the wind is relative to the boat. We are also ignoring everything except for the wind.

Comment: Have you tried modelling this mathematically, somehow? Maybe you can assume that the "sailing angle" is $x$ and see what happens then?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "best angle to sail at"? What is it that should be optimized? The speed of the boat? Time to a goal? Drag/Fuel consumption?

Answer (score 0):

[image]For a simple model we assume that:

- the sail is fixed perpendicular to the axis of the boat, or mathematically, the boat axis is the normal of the plain the sail locates in.
- The direction of boat(or steering the boat) is ruled by Rudder.
- with a certain angle there exist two force components; one aligned with the boat axis, another perpendicular to axis.The first one drives the boat forward and the second is lateral and push the boat aside.
- For NE the fourth quarter of an vertical ellipse is the path of the boat.

  The equation of ellipse is:

  $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

For the boat $a$ is the distance it moves to East and $b$ is the distance it moves to North. Suppose the fluid dynamic shape of the boat is such that the ratio of these parameters is:

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{10}{1}$

that means  a 10 meter motion forward is associated with 1 meter lateral motion.Then the equation of path, as shown in figure is:

$$y-d=-10\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Where d is for transformation when the center of ellipse is moved from (0, 0) to (0, d). Let $y-d=Y$ for simplicity and the boat starts moving from origin O then the vector of the speed of the boat at a location like A must make $10^O$ with y axis that is we must have:

$$Y'=\frac{10 x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}= \tan(80^o)≈5.67$$

⇒$x ≈0.5$

Plugging x in equation we get $Y=8.66$, so the boat has move from (0, 0) to (0.5, 8.66) and we have:

$tan(\alpha)=\frac{8.66}{0.5}=17.32$

$⇒ \alpha≈86.7^o$

This is the angle between the axis of the boat and x axis at point(location) A, that is the boat has turned $90^o-86.7^o=3.3^o$ clockwise.This angle plus $10^o$  will be total angle with y axis which is necessary  for $N40^oE$.So the desired angle must be $13.3^o$.